# Iteratively load large spatial dataset and perform intersection in R

Tags: r, bigdata, intersection, r-sf

I have a 20GB GeoPackage that I need to intersect with a much smaller GeoPackage (100mb). If the file sizes were smaller, then this would work:

```
library(sf)

BigDataset <- st_read("https://automaticknowledge.org/gb/greenspace/Manchester_greenspace.gpkg") 
Dataset <- st_read("https://automaticknowledge.org/gb/wards/Manchester_wards.gpkg")

Intersection <- Dataset %>%
    st_intersection(., BigDataset) %>%
    st_collection_extract(., "POLYGON")
```

However, due to the size of the 20GB file my R session crashes. Is there a way to iteratively load only part of the 20GB GeoPackage at a time (say chunking it into 1000 row groups) and perform the intersection on each chunk before ultimately generating a single 'Intersection' output once all the data has been loaded and processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck that you are dealing with geopackages. For a geopackage is a database (sqlite to be technical) and can be queried using SQL.

Consider this piece of code; what it does is:

- first it creates a geopackage to work with (your original code was not quite reproducible)
- lists the layers of your database, so that you know how to construct your from clause
- performs a sql query selecting rows between 5 and 17; these numbers are of course arbitrary and you will want to supply your own

To construct the sql code for iteration consider using the [`{glue}`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glue) package..

Also, and this may be somewhat of out of scope, it should be possible to perform the operation entirely in database using spatial SQL functions, omitting R which is memory constrained.

```r
library(sf)

# load the much loved North Carollina shapefile
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# create a geopackage, any geopackage...
st_write(shape, "nc.gpkg")

# to know your layers & construct your from clause
st_layers("nc.gpkg")

iter_read <- st_read("nc.gpkg", query = "select * from nc where rowid between 5 and 17;")
```

Comment: That's great thanks. Slight tangent, do you know how you return the total number of features in a GeoPackage without loading the whole thing?

Comment: @Chris yup - you can repurpose the query parameter of the above sf::st_read() to return not a subset, but count of rows - such as `total_rows <- st_read("nc.gpkg", query = "select count(*) as count_rows from nc;")$count_rows`. You will get a warning that no simple feature column is present (how could it be? :) that can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thanks. That does work, but I found as it still requires the entire dataset to be loaded first it took a long time to run (over an hour in my case). However, I had forgotten `st_layers` can give you the same answer much quicker:  `total_rows <- st_layers("nc.gpkg")$features[1]`