# Spatial query a geopackage with a subset of another geopackage when loading in sf

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to intersect a GeoPackage with a subset of another GeoPackage when reading in the data using `st_read`.

I know this can be done once the data are loaded:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

Boundaries <- st_read("https://automaticknowledge.org/gb/wards/Manchester_wards.gpkg")
Buildings <- st_read("https://automaticknowledge.org/gb/buildings/Manchester_buildings.gpkg")

Buildings_Intersection <- Buildings %>%
    st_intersection(., Boundaries %>% filter(WD21CD == "E05011363"))
```

However, with larger datasets I don't want to load in the entire dataset first to then do the intersection. I know `st_read` allows for queries, however, I am not sure how in my example 'Buildings_Intersection' can be achieved without loading all of the Buildings dataset.

This is a follow-on question from this: [Iteratively load large spatial dataset and perform intersection in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76527758/iteratively-load-large-spatial-dataset-and-perform-intersection-in-r) which proved to be a dead-end when using my actual data.

Comment: Way down, among the examples for `sf_read` (https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_read.html#ref-examples ) there's one example suggesting you can set a bounding box (in WKT format) as a spatial query filter for gpkg. Maybe you can employ the bounding box of your selected  boundary ("E05011363") to filter the building-DB before intersecting?

Comment: You can split the Buildings dataset in queries using `query = select ...` as @JindraLacko shows in previous post. And `rbind` the outputs of `Buildings_Intersections` On the other hand, if memory resource is a limit, I would suggest to use postrgesql + postgis. Or even duckdb, if the spatial extension is already there (https://duckdb.org/2023/04/28/spatial.html)